# 'HttpRequest' does not contain a definition for 'Url'

Tags: c#

```
public IActionResult Register(SysUser usr)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            ViewData["Message"] = "Invalid Input";
            ViewData["MsgType"] = "warning";
            return View("UserRegister");
        }
        else
        {
            string insert =
               @"INSERT INTO SysUser (UserId, UserPw, FullName, Email, CorporateId, UserRole) VALUES
             ('{0}', HASHBYTES('SHA1', '{1}'), '{2}', '{3}', {4}, 'user')";
            if (DBUtl.ExecSQL(insert, usr.UserId, usr.UserPw, usr.FullName, usr.Email) == 1)
            {
                usr.ActivationToken = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
                if (usr.ActivationToken != null)
                {
                    string inst = @"INSERT INTO SysUser(Active)VALUES('1')";
                    if (DBUtl.ExecSQL(inst, usr.Active) == 1)
                    {



                        string template = @"Hi {0},<br/><br/>
                           you have successfully created an account at Parkway Pantai Health Screening Portal.
Please click on the link below to verify your email address and complete your registration. Your user id is <b>{1}</b> and password is <b>{2}</b>.
                           <br/>";

                        template+= "</br><a href= '" + Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.Replace("CS.aspx", "CS_Activation.aspx?ActivationToken"+ usr.ActivationToken
                            ) + "'>Click here to activate your account.</a>";


                        string title = "Registration Successul - Welcome";
                        string message = String.Format(template, usr.FullName, usr.UserId, usr.UserPw);
                        string result = "";

                        bool outcome = false;
                        // TODO: L10 Task 2b - Call EmailUtl.SendEmail to send email
                        //                     Uncomment the following line with you are done
                        outcome = EmailUtl.SendEmail(usr.Email, title, message, out result);
                        if (outcome)
                        {
                            ViewData["Message"] = "User Successfully Registered";
                            ViewData["MsgType"] = "success";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            ViewData["Message"] = result;
                            ViewData["MsgType"] = "warning";
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ViewData["Message"] = DBUtl.DB_Message;
                        ViewData["MsgType"] = "danger";
                    }
                }
            }
            return View("UserRegister");
        }
    }
```

Hi all, I am trying to send a activation link using Guid.NewGuid() and when I want to generate a link using "Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.Replace" it shows a error where it says:

> 'HttpRequest' does not contain a definition for 'Url' and no accessible extension method 'Url' accepting a first argument of type 'HttpRequest' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?).

Is there any workaround to this? The framework i am using is c# .net framework 3.1. Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: are you trying to generate the base url of the site that you're running?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Related question about how to process verification after sending activation link.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65157675/9340890)

You can generate the base url of the site using the following:

```
string baseUrl = string.Format("{0}://{1}", 
                       HttpContext.Request.Scheme, HttpContext.Request.Host);
```

where `HttpContext.Request.Scheme` returns `http/https` 
and `HttpContext.Request.Host` is the host i.e.(localhost or [www.example.com](http://www.example.com)). 
So basically you will get `https://www.example.com`

Then, you can combine the `Guid` as a query string and send it to the user.

```
var activationUrl = $"{baseUrl}/Controller/Action?code={Guid.NewGuid()}";
```

Note: I've used variation to combine strings just for the answer. [Later](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated) is available starting with C# 6.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Thanks - updated. It's not required here for all similar type objects. But `Object[]` can be passed as well as per the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.format?view=net-5.0#System_String_Format_System_String_System_Object___). I just copied from one of our project and pasted it here.

Comment: Yeah, of course it's valid, it's what `params` does internally; however, I have never seen that syntax used in the 7 years I've been programming, so it struck me as really odd. Also, there are overloads for up to 3 arguments, so creating an array kills the benefit here

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto that's right. I generally avoid arrays in param (and mostly everywhere where possible). but this was written by another developer few years ago and it was just carried over as is because it doesn't change the behavior across different projects. But it's always good to know the unnecessary ways of coding. thanks for drawing my attention to it.

Comment: @Pirate Thank you so much for this piece of information, I managed to integrate and it worked successfully

Comment: @ImtryingtogetAforprojplshelp glad it helped, cheers!