# Verify user using activation link to activate profile

Tags: c#

I am using .net framework C# 3.1, I managed to call and send a activation link by generating `Guid.NewGuid()`. After user have registered, I sent a normal email to the user with a link to the activation page. How do I use generated `Guid` to get user's data? How to verify user's account using the generated `Guid`?

```
string insert =
@"INSERT INTO SysUser (UserId, UserPw, FullName, Email, CorporateCode, UserRole, Active, ActivationToken) VALUES
('{0}', HASHBYTES('SHA1', '{1}'), '{2}', '{3}', '{4}', 'user',0, NEWID() )";

if (DBUtl.ExecSQL(insert, usr.UserId, usr.UserPw, usr.FullName, usr.Email, usr.CorporateCode, usr.UserRole, usr.Active, usr.ActivationToken) == 1)
{
DBUtl.ExecSQL(LASTLOGIN_SQL, usr.UserId);
string baseUrl = string.Format("{0}://{1}",HttpContext.Request.Scheme,HttpContext.Request.Host);

string template = @"Hi {0},<br/><br/>
You have successfully created an account at Parkway Pantai Health Screening Portal.
Please click on the link below to verify your email address and complete your registration. Your user id is <b>{1}</b> and password is <b>{2}</b>. You may change your password anytime by going to the profile settings page.<br/>";

template += "</br><a href= '" + $"{baseUrl}/Account/Verify?t={usr.ActivationToken}" + "'>Click here to activate your account.</a>";

string title = "Registration Successful - Welcome";
string message = String.Format(template, usr.FullName, usr.UserId, usr.UserPw, usr.ActivationToken);
string result;
}
```

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public async Task<IActionResult> Verify(string t)
{
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(t))
{

return RedirectToAction("Register");
}

try
{
var user = _dbContext.SysUser.Where(u=>u.ActivationToken.Equals(t)).FirstOrDefault();
if (user != null)
{
user.Verified = true;
_dbContext.Update(user);
await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();

}
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
TempData["Message"] = "active ";
TempData["MsgType"] = "warning";
             
}
return RedirectToAction(REDIRECT_ACTN, REDIRECT_CNTR);
}
```

```
<a href="http://localhost:49614/Account/Verify?t=00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" </a>
```

Thank you for the help in advance

Comment: You should store guid with user's data in database. When user clicks in the link it will come to your controller action, you get the guid from it and get the user details from the db for that guid.

Comment: Store that activation token in database. Configure link to make request to specific controller/action and pass token as parameter. In action method, fetch user by token, if found, update activate flag (or whatever you have) and save changes.

Comment: @Pirate could you give an example if possible in coding terms: 'Configure link to make request to specific controller/action and pass token as parameter', if there is any link or example that I could follow it will be really helpful

Comment: @ImtryingtogetAforprojplshelp I've added an answer. let me know if you have doubts and mark the answer as accepted if it helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Related question about how to generate activation link.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65130755/9340890)

You can achieve this by creating a controller action that sets some flags/values in users table. Action method calls a service which will fetch user from database by verification code and if found, update some fields and save it back. You can have all your logic in controller, but that is not a good practice.

**Controller/Action:**

```
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    // constructors and other methods
  
    [HttpGet]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Verify(string t)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(t))
        {
            // invalid token, return to login page or error page as per the needs
            return RedirectToAction("Login");
        }
        
        var success = await _service.VerifyUserAsync(t);
        if (success)
        {
             // account verified
        }
        else
        {
            // error occured
        }
        return View();
    }
}
```

**Service:**

```
public async Task<bool> VerifyUserAsync(string t)
{
    var success = false;
    try
    {
        var user = await _repo.GetUserByTokenAsync(t);
        if(user != null)
        {
             user.Verified = true;
             await _repo.UpdateAsync(user);   // update user in database
            success = true;   // indicate everything processed fine
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
    }
    return success;
}
```

When generating an activation link, prepare url to point to this controller/action. and save activation token in user's record, so we can fetch user based on that during verify as shown above.

```
string activationtoken = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
string baseUrl = string.Format("{0}://{1}", HttpContext.Request.Scheme, HttpContext.Request.Host);
var activationUrl = $"{baseUrl}/Account/Verify?t={activationtoken}";
// save activationtoken in user's record
```

Remember, the query string `t` should match with an action method parameter `string t`, otherwise it won't be mapped and you'll never have the token.

**UPDATE** (if not following service-repo pattern)
**Controller/Action:**

```
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    // constructors and other methods
  
    [HttpGet]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Verify(string t)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(t))
        {
            // invalid token, return to login page or error page as per the needs
            return RedirectToAction("Login");
        }
        
        try
        {
            var user = _context.Users.Where(u=>u.ActivationToken==t).FirstOrDefault();
            if(user != null)
            {
                 user.Verified = true;
                 _context.Update(user);   // update user in database
                 await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
        }
        return View();
    }
}
```

Comment: May I ask where do I add the 'service' part above in Visual Studio? Do I add it in a new view folder?

Comment: Is the (string t) referring to string activationtoken? If I have changed my activationtoken into an attribute (usr.ActivationToken) in my database, inserting the Guid using NEWID(), what can I replace (string t) with?

Comment: It says that _repo and _service does not exist in current context, what could that mean?

Comment: @ImtryingtogetAforprojplshelp as I said, you could have all your code in controller if your project structure is different. Service and Repository is a nice way to separate business logic and keep controllers clean. `_repo' is just an another class which handles database related operations such as fetch, insert, update, etc. Instead of `_repo`, you could just write something like `_context.Users.Where(u=>u.ActivationToken=token).FirstOrDefault()`. Same with `_service`. [Read this](https://exceptionnotfound.net/the-repository-service-pattern-with-dependency-injection-and-asp-net-core/)

Comment: @ImtryingtogetAforprojplshelp if you're not following Service-Repo pattern, you can have all your logic in controller. I've updated my answer. [To learn more about Repository-Service pattern, see here](https://exceptionnotfound.net/the-repository-service-pattern-with-dependency-injection-and-asp-net-core/)

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late update, I have added 'user' in my SysUser database with Guid datatype however when I execute my project the user value returns null, what could be the reason for this error?

Comment: @ImtryingtogetAforprojplshelp hey, I can't say offhand why this would be happening. You can check the database first if record is properly added. If not, the problem is with add. If record is fine in db, check how you fetch the record, may be thats the problem. It would be ideal to post a new question with all related code such as adding user, fetching user, sample data from database. so it's easy to understand.

Comment: I have edited the codes above, and I found out that the t={usr.ActivationToken} does not correctly represent the actual value of the ActivationToken generated from Guid.NewGuid(). Please let me know if you need me to elaborate further! Thank you

Comment: @ImtryingtogetAforprojplshelp yes, please elaborate. What do you mean by _"t={usr.ActivationToken} does not correctly represent the actual value"_? Is activation token properly saved in database for user record? May be it possible that comparison was case-sensitive? Are you able to fetch user based on activation token? Exactly on which line the problem occurs and what happens? What do you expect that line to do?

Comment: When I inspect the activation link sent to the gmail, the activation token string/ the code for the link is <"/Account/Verify?t=00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" </a> , however the guid stored in my database is like: 0xA69A1F0CDAD0564EA6AD438791F0C598. When I clicked on the activation token link, the error line that showed up is : catch (Exception ex) where it is shown as "active" on the page redirected.

Comment: @ImtryingtogetAforprojplshelp looks like in url, its empty guid value. Are you generating guid token with `Guid.NewGuid()` or something else? `0xA69A1F0CDAD0564EA6AD438791F0C598` representation of `guid` doesn't look good. what database are you using?

Comment: Sorry, I generated using NEWID(), to insert ActivationToken into my database not Guid.NewGuid(), and I am using MS SQL.

Comment: @ImtryingtogetAforprojplshelp ok, that's valid syntax for sql server. but if you used that in your query, how do get value to use in url? can you post your full code where you generate the url and save token into the database. Looks like you're saving a different guid in database and using different in url.

Comment: @ImtryingtogetAforprojplshelp nevermind, i saw what you're doing. i would suggest, generate a guid using `Guid.NewGuid()` in your code. then save it into the database. and use the same value in url as well. currently, you're inserting the record first with value generate by database (not known to your code), so it very likely that `usr.ActivationToken` doesn't have proper value when you send email.

Comment: @ImtryingtogetAforprojplshelp what is the datatype of `ActivationToken` column in the table?

Comment: The datatype of ActivationToken is varbinary, should I change it to uniqueidentifier?

Comment: @ImtryingtogetAforprojplshelp yes, definitely. that way database will hold correct value you need as a token. then you just need to keep the token in url and value in database in sync somehow depending on your code structure and it should be good.

Comment: okay, I will try out your suggestion and thank you so much for your prompt replies!